# How to call Controller method in same Controller..?Below is the Code Shown

Tags: java, spring-boot

*I am Allowing only admin to update data it's successfull, but if a person directly calls updatePlayersDataAfterMatch in postman then it will give PlayerDetailNotFoundException ,so how to give AdminNeedToLoginFirstException.*

**Controller Class Code:-**

@PostMapping(value="/foradminLoginOTPgeneration")

```
public  ResponseEntity<HashMap<String,Object>> adminLoginOTPgeneration(@Valid @RequestBody Admin admin) {
     HashMap<String, Object> adminLogin = service.adminLoginOTPgeneration(admin);
     
     if(! adminLogin.isEmpty()) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(adminLogin,HttpStatus.OK); 
     }else {
         throw new InValidUserNameException("Username invalid or password incorrect" + admin.getUsername());
     }
     
}
 @PostMapping(value="/enterOTPforLogin/{otp}")
 public ResponseEntity<Boolean> adminLoginwithOTP(@Valid @PathVariable @NotNull(message="please enter otp") String otp) {
     boolean successfull = service.adminLoginwithOTP(otp);
     IPLController controller =new IPLController();
     
     if (successfull) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(successfull,HttpStatus.OK); 
            
        } else {
            throw new OTPWrongEnteredException("OTP Entered is wrong please regenerate it");
        }
 }
 
 @PutMapping(value = "/updateplayerdataaftermatch")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> updatePlayersDataAfterMatch(@Valid @RequestBody Param param) {
        
     boolean updatePlayersDataAfterMatch = service.updatePlayersDataAfterMatch(param);
     
        if (updatePlayersDataAfterMatch) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(updatePlayersDataAfterMatch,HttpStatus.OK); 
            
        } else {
            return new throw new PlayerDetailNotFoundException("The player you are trying to update has spelling mistake or doesn't exist" +  param.getPlayerName());
            
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect if something goes wrong as per your application.

Example in your code.

```
@PutMapping(value = "/updateplayerdataaftermatch")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> updatePlayersDataAfterMatch(@Valid @RequestBody Param param) {
        
     boolean updatePlayersDataAfterMatch = service.updatePlayersDataAfterMatch(param);
     
        if (updatePlayersDataAfterMatch) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(updatePlayersDataAfterMatch,HttpStatus.OK); 
            
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).location(URI.create("/getAdminDetails")).build();

            //return new throw new PlayerDetailNotFoundException("The player you are trying to update has spelling mistake or doesn't exist" +  param.getPlayerName());
            
        }   
    }
```

Explanation: The above code will check whether the to redirect to admin or give direct response.

I hope, it helps!

Comment: Sir i want to give an exception to user that Admin must login for this updateplayersdataaftermatch method

Comment: just use '''this''' keyword to get the instance of current class @AnkushKamble